# LINUX - Last login for root user

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, rhel, login

on a redhat server I logged with my domain username, and then switched as root.
As I switched as root I received the message for the last login for root (Last login: ....).
I am asking if the "last login" message displays the date that every user logged/switched as root, or it displays the date that my username switched as root.
The strange thing is that the date displayed for the last login as root was 2 month before the last record in wtmp.
Thanks a lot, best of all.

Answer (score 1):

You did not elaborate on what exactly you mean by "switched as root". I assume you were using the command `su -`, possibly in the form `sudo su -`. As described on its manpage, this command starts a new login shell for the root user. The "last login" message reports the last time a login shell was started for the same user.

In response to your question this means that the "last login" message appearing after `su -` reports the last time *anyone* switched to root via `su -` *or* logged in directly as root. The same holds for the "last login" message appearing when you log in directly as root.

Comment: Hi! I've used the command "sudo su -", it's the same for "su - root", true?

Comment: Correct. I have updated my answer to clarify.